# Creating a meshgrid from a matrix in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I want to make a matplotlib contour plot. To do that I need to define a vector Lat, Lon and Den. There are 128 unique values for Lat and Lon which accounts for 16384 possible pairs. I already have a matrix which has a column for Lat, Lon and Den. However, the size of this matrix is 10946. This means that there are pairs of Lat-Lon that don't have a Den associated to it and which I would like to take the value of 0. An example would be the following:

```
     Matrix = array([[ 1.5,  0.9,  1.5],
                     [ 1.5,  1.5,  1  ],
                     [ 2.9,  1.5,  2  ]])
```

The first column is Lat, the second is Lon and the third one is density. I can create a meshgrid using:

```
    Lat, Lon = np.mesgrid(set(Matrix[:,0]), set(Matrix[:,1]))
```

And this will return 6 combinations. How do I make an array "Den" such that takes the values in my original matrix for a pair Lat- Lon and 0 otherwise? If loops can be avoided, the better.

Comment: While this is not an answer to the actual question, you can always plot a `tricontour` plot: `plt.tricontourf(Matrix[:,0], Matrix[:,1], Matrix[:,2])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a table like this near the point `(lat=30, long=20)` for example:

```
# tab= array([
#        [ 30.1310486 ,  20.86128027,   0.34034154],
#        [ 30.44384707,  20.84228301,   0.14557502],
#        [ 30.7601326 ,  20.9971842 ,   0.16993092],
#        ..., 
#        [ 30.3797119 ,  20.47931737,   0.08614626],
#        [ 30.37689017,  20.8116245 ,   0.60779073],
#        [ 30.33829254,  20.02353876,   0.31654195]])
# shape  (10946, 3)
```

You can use `np.unique` instead of `set`, which provides useful inverse indexes labelling latitudes and longitudes with integers:

```
lat,long,den = tab.T
uniq_lat,inv_lat = np.unique(lat,return_inverse=True)
uniq_long,inv_long = np.unique(long,return_inverse=True)
```

Then build a complete density grid:

```
dims = uniq_lat.size,uniq_long.size     
new_den=np.zeros(dims) # unknown values
new_den[inv_lat,inv_long]=den   # known values
```

And rebuild a (sorted) complete table:

```
new_lat,new_long=meshgrid(uniq_lat,uniq_long)
new_tab=np.concatenate((new_lat,new_long,new_den)).reshape(3,-1).T
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however, Lat and Lon are not always integers so this approach does not work.

Comment: They was on your first post ;)  describe your matrix furthermore to help the helpers.

Comment: I edit the post with float `lat` and `long`, and reformat the output on three columns.